# ASCII game in console

Tags: c++, classes, windows, role-playing-game

Overall, I want to make a game in console, something Pokemon-like but with typical rpg scenery - swords, magic and all that. I want to make player able to move around the map, find dungeons, fight some monsters (in a round-like maner, like Pokemon but you fight yourself, four moves, being able to escape, potions, etc.), take treasures. I just want to know if I am on a right path. I'll take ratings, suggestions, ideas, everything. Mostly I want to know if I include right files and if this structure of classes is optimal.

Everything else is here: [https://github.com/supermaciu/ascii-rpg-game-official](https://github.com/supermaciu/ascii-rpg-game-official/tree/8db3c0860a70f68b03c0fb7312874670b69aba41)

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include <algorithm>

#include "Utilities.h"

#include "Game.h"
#include "BoardObject.h"
#include "Board.h"
#include "Player.h"
#include "Enemy.h"
#include "Teleport.h"

// TODO: optimize 
// TODO: file reader, txt to board setup
// FIX: why does it take so much time to compile
// TODO: Board function to move a BoardObject to another board
// TODO: optimize Board.cpp coloring
// IDEA: console window widens on inventory open on the right side / slowly
// TODO: threading / doing things while waiting on input

int main() {

    //Init
    srand(time(NULL));
    bool running = true;
    bool debug_mode = true;

    //Game / Config
    Game game;
    game.setTitle("ascii-rpg-game");
    game.setCursorVisibility(false);
    game.resizeWindow(get_screen_width()*0.85, get_screen_height()*0.8);
    game.moveWindowCenter();
    game.setConsoleBufferSize(0, 0);
    //game.maxemizeWindow(true);
    game.resizeableWindow(false);
    //game.resizeableWindow(true); // not working
    //game.disableInput(true);

    Board* board = new Board("board1", 10, 10, &game);
    game.set_current_board(board);

    Player* player = new Player(1, 1, board);

    //Board 2
    Board* board2 = new Board("board2", 15, 5, &game);

    Board* board3 = new Board("sklep", 8, 8, &game);

    // TODO: shop template
    
    Teleport* t1 = new Teleport(3, 3, board);
    t1->setDestination(0, 0, board2);

    Teleport* t2 = new Teleport(3, 3, board2);
    t2->setDestination(0, 0, board);

    Teleport* t3 = new Teleport(5, 3, board);
    t3->setDestination(0, 0, board);

    Teleport* t4 = new Teleport(1, 8, board);
    t4->setDestination(0, 0, board3);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < board->get_width(); i++) {
        Void* v = new Void(i, 5, board);
    }

    //Input
    char move;

    //Initial board draw
    player->eventsHandler(move);
    game.showBoard();

    while (running) {
        move = getch();

        if (move == -32) {
            move = getch();
        }

        if (move == 3 || move == 27) {
            running = false;
        } else if (move == 9) {
            if (debug_mode == false) {
                debug_mode = true;
            } else {
                debug_mode = false;
            }
        }

        player->eventsHandler(move);

        game.showBoard();

        //Debug
        game.debug(debug_mode, player);

        Sleep(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Teleport.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

#include "BoardObject.h"
//has to be included -> Teleport is a derived class
class Board;

class Teleport : public BoardObject {
    private:
        unsigned int dest_x = 0;
        unsigned int dest_y = 0;
        Board* dest_board = nullptr;

        bool tp_set = false;
        bool dynamic = false;
    public:
        Teleport(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, Board* board);

        ~Teleport();

        bool is_set() { return tp_set; }
        
        void setDestination(unsigned int x2, unsigned int y2, Board* board2, bool dynamic=false);
        void unsetDestination();

        void onTouchEvent(Player* player) override;
};
```

Game.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

#include "Utilities.h"

class Board;
class BoardObject;
class Player;

class Game {
    private:
        std::string game_name;

        HWND consoleWindow; // console window handle
        HANDLE handle; // handles changes made to command prompt
        
        COORD coord; // coordinates
        CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO consoleCursorInfo; // console cursor options

        std::vector<Board*> boards = {};
        Board* current_board = nullptr;
    
    public:
        Game() = default;
    
        Game(const std::string& game_name);

        ~Game();
        
        HANDLE get_handle() { return this->handle; }

        void setTitle(const std::string& game_name);
        void setCursorVisibility(bool show_cursor);
        void resizeWindow(int width, int height);
        void moveWindow(int x, int y);
        void moveWindowCenter();
        void setConsoleBufferSize(int x, int y);
        void maxemizeWindow(bool maxemize);
        void resizeableWindow(bool can_resize);
        void disableInput(bool disable);

        Board* get_current_board() { return this->current_board; };
        void set_current_board(Board *board);
        
        void showBoard();
        
        Board* getBoardByName(const std::string& name);
        std::vector<Board*> getAllBoards();
        std::vector<BoardObject*> getAllBoardObjects();
        
        void addBoard(Board* board) { boards.push_back(board); }
        
        void debug(bool debug_mode, Player *player);
};
```

Board.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>
#include <string>

class Game;

class BoardObject;

class Board {
    private:
        Game *game;

        const int BOARD_LIMIT_MIN = 2;
        const int BOARD_LIMIT_MAX = 100;

        std::string name = "nullBoard";

        int width;
        int height;

        char board[100][100] = {};
        std::vector<BoardObject*> board_objects = {};
    public:
        Board(unsigned int width, unsigned int height, Game* game);

        Board(const std::string& name, unsigned int width, unsigned int height, Game* game);

        std::string get_name() { return this->name; }
        void set_name(std::string name) { this->name = name; }

        int get_width() { return this->width; }
        int get_height() { return this->height; }

        void render();
        void draw();

        bool hasBoardObjects();

        void addToBoard(BoardObject* board_object);
        void deleteFromBoard(BoardObject* board_object, bool delete_object_in_memory);

        std::vector<BoardObject*> getBoardObjects();
        BoardObject* getBoardObjectById(int id);
        std::vector<BoardObject*> getBoardObjectsByClassname(std::string classname);
        BoardObject* getBoardObjectByCoords(int x, int y);

        friend class Game;
};
```

BoardObject.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

#include "Game.h"

class Board;
class Player;

class BoardObject {
    protected:
        Game *game;
        
        unsigned int x;
        unsigned int y;

        char c;
        int color = 0x07; // 0x, 0 -> black, 7 -> console white
        
        unsigned int id;
        static unsigned int ID;

        std::string classname = "nullBoardObject";
        
        bool moveInto= false;
        bool interactWith = false;

        Board* board;

    public:
        BoardObject(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, char c, Board* board);

        std::string get_classname() { return this->classname; }

        int get_id() { return this->id; }

        int get_x() { return this->x; }
        int get_y() { return this->y; }
        void set_pos(int x, int y);

        char get_char() { return this->c; }
        void set_char(char c) { this->c = c; }

        int get_color() { return this->color; }
        void set_color(int color) { this->color = color; }

        Board* get_board() { return this->board; }
        void set_board(Board* board) { this->board = board; }
        
        bool get_moveInto() { return this->moveInto; }
        void set_moveInto(bool canMoveInto) { this->moveInto = canMoveInto; }

        bool get_interactWith() { return this->interactWith; }
        void set_interactWith(bool canBeInteractedWith) { this->interactWith = canBeInteractedWith; }
        
        virtual void onEnterEvent(Player* player) {};
        virtual void onTouchEvent(Player* player) {};
        
        friend class Game;
        friend class Board;
};

class Void : public BoardObject {
    public:
        Void(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, Board* board);
};
```

Player.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

#include "BoardObject.h"
#include "Board.h"

#include "Teleport.h"

class Player : public BoardObject {
    public:
        char move;
        int kill_count = 0;

        Teleport* t1 = nullptr;
        Teleport* t2 = nullptr;
    private:
        int dirx = 0;
        int diry = 0;

        int prev_x;
        int prev_y;
        char prev_move;
    public:
        Player(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, Board* board);

        //BoardObject functions
        void set_pos(int x, int y);
        
        //Player functions
        int get_dirx() { return dirx; }
        int get_diry() { return diry; }

        int get_prev_x() { return prev_x; }
        int get_prev_y() { return prev_y; }
        char get_prev_move() { return prev_move; }

        bool canMoveInto(int x, int y);
        bool canMoveInto(BoardObject* bo);

        void movementHandler(char move);
        void checkOnEnterEvents();
        void checkOnTouchEvents();
        void eventsHandler(char move);
};
```

Enemy.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

#include "BoardObject.h"
class Board;

class Enemy : public BoardObject {
    public:
        Enemy(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, Board* board);
        
        void onEnterEvent(Player* player) override;
};
```

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community. We only review code that is working as expected, there are other sites that will help you design your code. The question is currently off-topic because the C++ source files are not included. While we can use repositories as reference material, we can only review the code included in the question itself. Please read [Where can I get help?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Unnecessary use of `this->`

You almost never have to write `this->` in C++. The exception is when you have member function arguments whose names are the same as member variables, like you do in the constructors. There are two ways around this:

1. Use a different name for the member function argument, like appending a `_`.
2. Use [member initializer lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor).

An example of the latter would be:

```
Board::Board(unsigned int width, unsigned int height, Game* game):
    width(std::clamp(width, BOARD_LIMIT_MIN, BOARD_LIMIT_MAX)),
    height(std::clamp(height, BOARD_LIMIT_MIN, BOARD_LIMIT_MAX)),
    game(game)
{
    game->addBoard(this);
}
```

## Avoid manual memory management

Avoid calling `new` and `delete` where possible, and let containers manage their memory, or use smart pointers like `std::unique_ptr`. Manual memory management often ends with memory leaks. For example, the `Board`s allocated in `main()` are never `delete`d. Also, you didn't write a destructor for `class Board`, so if a `Board` is deleted abut still had some items in `board_objects`, those items will have leaked as well.

For `board_objects`, since you only know the base type, you can use `std::unique_ptr` like so:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<BoardObject>> board_objects;
```

In `addToBoard()` you would only need to replace `push_back()` with `emplace_back()`. And you can remove the `delete` statement from `deleteFromBoard()`.

However, that still requires you to `new` an object before calling `addToBoard()`. You could have `addToBoard()` take a `std::unique_ptr<BoardObject>` as an r-value parameter, create new objects using `std::make_unique<DerivedObject>` and then `std::move()` them around, but that's also cumbersome. Let's revisit this:

## Don't let objects manage their own storage

I would avoid having objects derived from `BoardObject` add themselves to a `Board`. If a `Board` is going to own the objects, let the `Board` add them to itself. However, I can see that you don't want to have to write two lines of code every time, like so:

```
Enemy *enemy = new Enemy(x, y);
board->addToBoard(enemy);
```

Although you could make a oneliner out of it:

```
board->addToBoard(new Enemy(x, y));
```

But as said before, thisd way you are still allocating a derived object manually. Wouldn't it be nice if you could let `addToBoard()` create an object of the right type for you? You can do that if you make it a template, like so:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
void addToBoard(Args&&... args) {
    board_objects.push_back(            // Add to board_objects a
        std::make_unique<T>(            // new unique object of type T and
            std::forward<Args>(args...) // forward args to its constructor
        )
    );
}
```

If you're not used to templates, this might look a bit complicated, but the benefit of this is that the code *using* it will be much simpler to write. For example, to add an enemy to the board, now you just have to write:

```
board->addToBoard<Enemy>(x, y);
```

If you need a pointer to the object you just added, you can modify `addToBoard()` to return a pointer to the object you just pushed to the vector:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
T* addToBoard(Args&&... args) {
    ...
    return board_objects.back().get();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me much.

Comment: Could you anwer me one more question? Why does it take so much to compile while using ".h" files?

Comment: So much time? Memory? Disk space? Your code doesn't look like it should use much of anything though. Certainly using header files should not affect compile times significantly, and it's standard practice to write header files.

Comment: Time, it takes like 10s to compile on my side. Is this normal? I am using g++ to compile, and VS Code if that means anything.

Comment: Maybe because of inline functions? In Utilities.h